# Reporting Endpoints not parsing

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers, error-reporting

In my localhost page, I am returning this header:

```
Reporting-Endpoints: main-endpoint="https://[brand].report-uri.com/a/d/g", csp-endpoint="https://[brand].report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce", cspro-endpoint="https://[brand].report-uri.com/r/d/csp/reportOnly"
```

Where [brand] is my company's name in as a single lowercase word.

When I open Chrome's Reporting API view in the Application tab, I can see that no endpoints were parsed. But when I open https://reporting-api-demo.glitch.me/page, I can see two such endpoints parsed. They set:

```
reporting-endpoints: main-endpoint="https://reports-endpoint.glitch.me/main", default="https://reports-endpoint.glitch.me/default"
```

I've tried using the same lowercase header name they did, but it didn't work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working on our staging site, so I'm pretty sure it just doesn't work on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work on HTTP.
The reporting API Endpoints will be parsed on HTTPS.